# How to tranform my controller to retrieve the targetted data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on an MVC.NET application and I need help for one thing.
I need to get some data from my database to draw charts.
All is good but I need to make a chart for all the consummation of a vehicle, between two dates.
How can I do this?

I tried with this in my controller:

```
public ActionResult choice(string Snom/*The Name Of The InputBox where put the name*/
{
    var veh = from s in db.Fuel
              select s;
    var list = veh.ToList();

    List<double?> repartitions = new List<double?>();

    var comp = list.Select(x => x.VehicleId).Distinct();
    foreach (var item in comp)
    {
        repartitions.Add(list.Where(x => x.VehicleId == Snom).Sum(x => x.Volume));

    }
    var rep = repartitions;
    ViewBag.COMP = comp;
    ViewBag.REP = repartitions.ToList();

    return View();
}
```

I know where is my error because I asked a question before today with the same kind of stuff.

This code makes that in a chart:

[ScreenOfChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O4yR.png)

When I click on "Valider" it takes the values in that inputbox box ( In this case "B12") and makes the sum of all the record in the database and 38 points on the graph (which is the number of record in fact)

My DB structure is like that :[Db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlH4c.png)

How can I do that?

Thank a lot :)

EDIT ! :

I'll put some new info :

This is my view : [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/latpT.png)

When you are on it , you need to enter the name of a vehicle . For this exemple , i'll take the B12 . [exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61uFr.png)

When i click on "Valider" i have that : [after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvufH.png)

The chart show the sum of all volume and places 38 Dots ( which is the number of records of Volume) : [recordOfB12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVZCk.png)

I want to have a chart , which show all record separatly ( and not the sum of them ) and each value on each dot . Like : first dot :194.76... twenty-three : 202.68 and so on .

For now , the code is :

```
public ActionResult choice(string Snom , DateTime? date1 , DateTime? date2 )
        {
            var veh = from s in db.Fuel
                      select s;
            var list = veh.ToList();


            List<double?> repartitions = new List<double?>();


            var comp = list.Select(x => x.VehicleId).Distinct();
            foreach (var item in comp)
            {
                repartitions.Add(list.Where(x => x.VehicleId == Snom).Sum(x => x.Volume));

            }
            var rep = repartitions;
            ViewBag.COMP = comp;
            ViewBag.REP = repartitions.ToList();




            return View();
        }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I try to get the data from my model and put it in a chart . But , i don't know how to select the right datas between two dates ( who are in inputboxes) for the right vehicle.

Comment: Add a where clause to your first select: where s.RUNDATE >= Start and s.RUNDATE <= End

Comment: I must do that in the line who begin with " repartitions.add ? "

Comment: You can. But why reading all rows and filter in memory? I'll post my suggestion as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```cs
var veh = from s in db.Fuel
              where s.RUNDATE >= Start and s.RUNDATE <= End
              select s;
```

Comment: For the date , it will be good . But i have a problem before targetting between the dates : I can't select all the record for one vehicle . As the screenshot said , it collect the sum of all the record for the vehicle . First of all , before filtering between dates , i want to show all the record on the chart without regarding the ddates. i know that the line in trouble is that :     repartitions.Add(list.Where(x => x.VehicleId == Snom).Sum(x => x.Volume));

Comment: You should redesign your view model. Either you send the complete vehicle data to your client and create a grouped, filtered and summed subset there. Or you send the detailed records and your filtered sums to the client.

Comment: can't we do something like that ? 

`var veh = from s in db.Fuel                 
                      select s;
            var list = veh.ToList();

            List<double?> repartitions = new List<double?>();
            // we select the vehicle separatly
            var comp = list.Select(x => x.VehicleId).Distinct();
            //Tring to get all the record for one vehicle
            foreach (var item in comp)
            {
                repartitions.Add(list.Where(x => x.VehicleId == item));

            }`

Comment: This is not logical. You want to send different data  without changing the data you send?

Comment: Saw your second comment after posting. Your new code sends all vehicle ids and the records for the selected vehicle. So you do the filtering on the client side?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that we can do it  . ATM , the chart put 39 dot ( the number of record for the B12 vehicle) on a line who represent the sum of Volume for the B12 vehicle . So , the code understand that they are 39 record , and know the amount of each record. I just want to display each record separately. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O4yR.png)

Comment: To be honest. This is not helpful. Please add some sample data (input and expected output) to your question.

Comment: Edited aswell :) !

Comment: Sorry mate. Looking at chart screenshots tells me nothing about what data the controller action should send back. Please add a dotnet fiddle with your sample data, your logic and a description of the expected data output.

Comment: The controller must send something like this , for the "B12" vehicle : 

repartitions.Add(list.Where(x => x.VehicleId == Snom)(x => x.Volume));

The only problem is that i have the sum instead of each record